# Range for loop of a multi-dimensional array, what type to use?

Tags: c++, for-loop, types, range, auto

Hi I got a sligth problem, I'm trying to do a range for loop of a multidimensional array but I can't figure out what type to use. With this code the program works flawlessly but when I try to choose my type instead of auto I get errors, I've tried searching for the problem but haven't found anything. help would be appreciated!

```
int ia[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

for( auto &ref_ia : ia){

    for(int &ref_ref : ref_ia){

        cout << ref_ref << " ";

    }

}
```

Comment: it should be `int*` for the outer loop

Comment: `for (int (&ref_ia)[4] : ia)` [**See it live**](https://ideone.com/5V7vKI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element type is an array of 4 integers, so you want a reference to an array of 4 integers:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int ia[3][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12} };

    for (int (&ref_ia)[4] : ia)
    {
        for(int &ref_ref : ref_ia)
        {
            std::cout << ref_ref << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing something similar but I must have missed something while I made the reference.

Comment: Probably thanks to C's [awful declarator syntax](http://cdecl.org/?q=int%28%26ref_ia%29%5B4%5D) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hope the code below will enlight you of what `auto` is:

```
int main()
{
  int ia[3][4] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };

  for (int (&ref_ia)[4] : ia){

    for (int &ref_ref : ref_ia){

      cout << ref_ref << " ";

    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

`int (&ref_ia)[4]` is a reference to a four dimensional array or integers.